# How to add metadata to html file

Tags: java, html, metadata

I am using Apache Tika to convert RTF documents to HTML. 
In Tika's RTFParser class I made changes to generate HTML file using HTMLEditorKit and now I'm able to generate the HTML file.

I want to add the metadata tags into the  head tag of the generated HTML file.
Can anybody give me an idea to how to proceed?

Comment: BTW, FYI it should not be tagged as Java, It is HTML related question.

Comment: Do you want to do it using an API or by hand ?

Comment: i want to do it programatically, I am reading the generated html file and able to find the head tag, but looking for how to insert metadata into head tag

Comment: below is the way i am finding head in html page:

Comment: FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file1);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
     String theLine;    
     while ((theLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
      if(theLine.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("<head>"))
        
       System.out.println(theLine);
     }

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

[Add Metadata](http://tika.apache.org/0.6/api/org/apache/tika/metadata/Metadata.html#add%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

I'm not sure that this will help, but I think it is worth to check out.